# How to forward some sub-domain of a zone to default forwarders

Tags: bind, subdomain

I want to use bind9 to hijacking a zone,for example "qq.com",my zone configuration is

```
zone "qq.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "db.qq.com";
  forwarders { 119.29.29.29; 8.8.8.8; };
};
```

and my db file is

```
[root@cenotstest named]# cat db.qq.com
$TTL 1800
@           IN  SOA ns1.qq.com.  my.example.com. (
                    20210409 ;
                    3H ;
                    15M ;
                    1W ;
                    1D ) ;
            IN  NS  ns1.qq.com.
ns1             IN      A       183.36.112.46

a   IN   A  1.1.1.1
```

When resolving a.qq.com, I can get the correct answer as below

```
[root@cenotstest named]# nslookup a.qq.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   a.qq.com
Address: 1.1.1.1
```

But for other domains,like "mail.qq.com" or "www.qq.com"(maybe there are a lot of other domains I don't know).I Just want to forward these domains I do not know to name servers configured in the forwarders like 8.8.8.8 as default.

But now, the forwarders in zone "qq.com" doesn't work, Does the bind9 support it?

Comment: I believe there is no way to do that, at least, in BIND. If you "hijacked" a zone, it's yours now, set up everything by yourself.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov thank you, I am now using dnsmaq as a dns service, and I prepare to migrate dns from dnsmasq to bind9.  Dnsmasq can support it。If a domain doesn't match any record in my configuration, dnsmasq can read nameserver from /etc/resolv.conf as a default forwarder to resolv the domain. So I guess bind9 can support this feature too.

Comment: Look at bind RPZ feature.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks a lot, bind rpz works for me

Answer (score 0):

> If a domain doesn't match any record in my configuration, dnsmasq can read nameserver from /etc/resolv.conf as a default forwarder to resolv the domain. So I guess bind9 can support this feature too.

That is AFAIK  actually a unique feature of [dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq).

Normal DNS servers, like ISC Bind, are either recursive or authoritative. When they are authoritative for a (sub-) domain, they hold the complete truth for that (sub-) domain and their zone data contains all resource records that exist for the domain (although `NS` records can be used to delegate sub-domains to other name servers) . When an authoritative name server is queried for a record that it does not know about and which is not delegated, then as far as it is concerned,  that record doesn't exist. End-of-story.

You could try is delegating all non-existing records (using a DNS wild card) works by creating a zone file:

```
db.qq.com
$TTL 1800
@           IN  SOA ns1.qq.com.  my.example.com. (
                    20210409 ;
                    3H ;
                    15M ;
                    1W ;
                    1D ) ;
            IN  NS  ns1.qq.com.
ns1             IN      A       183.36.112.46

a   IN   A  1.1.1.1

the.original.authoritative.nameserver.for.qq.com. IN A 10.9.8.7 
*   IN NS the.original.authoritative.nameserver.for.qq.com.
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but bind doesn't support wildcard in domain delegate. I try to configure like this and the named process can't start.